# Redux subscribe gets triggered after unsubscribe

Tags: redux, react-redux

Subscribe function (and `pushDLEvent()` inside it) gets run once more after the unsubscribe is being run. What can cause that, and what might fix that?

This is happening only on some of the pages, and only on hard pageload/refresh.

```
const consentCheck = (eventName: string, store: Store) => {
    const state = store.getState()
    const consent = state.user.consent
    if (!pushDLEvent(eventName, consent)) {
        // Event did not get pushed, due to not passing consents. Probably consents did not get loaded before checking them. Listen for consent changes while user is still on the same page.
        const location = state.history.location
        const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
            const currentState = store.getState()
            if (JSON.stringify(consent) !== JSON.stringify(currentState.user.consent)) {
                pushDLEvent(eventName, currentState.user.consent)
            }
            if (
                JSON.stringify(location) !== JSON.stringify(currentState.history.location) ||
                JSON.stringify(consent) !== JSON.stringify(currentState.user.consent)
            ) {
                unsubscribe()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be an else if instead of if for the unsubscribe case, I see that there is an || condition being checked here and the same is being checked in the first if. Is that right? Both cases would be executed if the condition evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

In the first `if` you have a condition that satisfies same 2nd `if` statment, so logically your code is wrong.

Either make the conditions different, or use `else if`

Condition I am talking about is:
`JSON.stringify(consent) !== JSON.stringify(currentState.user.consent)`

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I don't think that that's the problem. The same condition is repeated in second if because i want `unsubscribe` to get called not only when the consent changes, but also when location changes. I've tried to call `unsubscribe` also in the first if statement, just before `pushDLEvent()`, while changing second if into else if that checks only for location change, but the problem persists :(